# Invalid Control Character Error in Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, gis, arcgis

I am receiving the following error when running the below python script.

ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 7591 column 220620 (char 385678)

I did some research on this and it appeared that it would be resolved by passing 'strict=false' within json.dumps(), but I'm still receiving the same error. This is the only REST service that I have attempted to query that returns this error.

```
import arcgis
import json

from arcgis import ArcGIS
service = ArcGIS("http://mapping.dekalbcountyga.gov/arcgis/rest/services/LandUse/MapServer")
query = service.get(0, count_only=False)
json_query = json.dumps(query, strict=False)
f = open("dekalb_parcels.geojson", "w")
f.write(json_query)
f.close()
```

Any help that can be provided would be very appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE - This is the full error that I am receiving.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\Scripts\dekalb_parcel_query.py", line 8, in <module>
    query = service.get(0, count_only=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\arcgis\arcgis.py", line 146, in get
    jsobj = self.get_json(layer, where, fields, count_only, srid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\arcgis\arcgis.py", line 90, in get_json
    return response.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 802, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 7591 column 220620 (char 385678)
```

Comment: This usually happens when you have escape sequences like `\r` or `\n` in the string you want to dump.

Comment: Klaus, I believe you're right. Passing 'strict=false' is supposed to ignore those escape sequences as far as I understand. However, in my case it does not seem to rectify the error. Unless I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: The `strict` parameter is available when parsing JSON, not when serializing.

Comment: I see, so how would I be able to avoid this error? I've also tried altering the code like so, 'json_query = json.dumps(query.replace('\r\n', '\\r\\n'))' in order to escape them manually. Please excuse my ignorance as I'm a pretty novice programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by passing `strict=False` within `return response.json()`